# Is the choice of test statistics in hypothesis testing a completely philosophical one?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Is the choice of test statistic in hypothesis testing a completely philosophical one? In other words, is the choice of test statistic and rejection/acceptance region a completely judgement call and is not bounded by any requirment?

Comment: By "rejection/acceptance region", I assume you mean $\alpha$, the type I error rate. What exactly do you mean by "test statistic" in this context? Eg, certainly the choice of, say, $\chi^2$ vs. $t$ is not just a "judgement call".

Comment: @gung When you do a hypothesis test, you are basically testing whether the test statistic generate a value in the rejection or acceptance region. z-score is an example.

Comment: Yes, a $z$-score is a test statistic, but choosing $z$ is certainly "bounded by... requirement[s]". Eg, you have to choose a test statistic that is appropriate for your data.

Comment: But that is still a judgement call, right? I could haven chosen a monotonic transformation $z-$score and change the acceptance/rejection region to accomodate this transformation so that the same set of data gives me the same result, namely reject or fail to reject.

Comment: If you have two sets of normally distributed data, & you want to determine if they come from populations w/ the same mean, & you don't know the variances a-priori (so you have to estimate them from the data), you should not use $z$--you should use $t$. I wouldn't refer to that as a "judgment call".

Comment: It seems to me that the comments discussion here is focussed on the statistical model which contains the test statistic. You would be using _z_ if the model has a specified (known) standard deviation, and _t_ if it didn't.

Comment: @Kun Do you mean to ask about the nature of the test statistic, or the alpha level for acceptance/rejection?

Comment: @MichaelLew I mean to ask about the nature of test statistic.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are asking about the choice of test statistic within a specific statistical model rather than asking about the choice of statistical model. I am also assuming that you are asking about the test statistic to be used in a classical hypothesis test in the accept/reject manner.

The choice of test statistic is made on the basis of the properties of the resulting test. There is good reason to choose the test statistic to optimise the power to discriminate between a true and false test hypothesis, but it is also useful that the distribution of the test statistic be known.

Student (Gossett) wanted to devise a significance test for means from small samples. His resulting t-test uses a particular test statistic, Student's t, not because he wanted to test the ratio of the mean and standard error, but because the distribution of that test statistic is derivable.

Whether you wish to call the choice of test statistic a "philosophical one" depends on what you mean by that.  ;-)